# npm bodyParser error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, body-parser

I am currently having a 400 error (Bad request) and can't find the reason for that. I suppose it is due to the bodyParser in the server... I used to be able to send information when it was not nested. However, now, having an object inside an object seems to unable the server from communicating.

**In the server**

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

**data sent**

```
 var to_send = {};
 to_send["something"] = {"field1": field1, "field2": field2};
```

[Server Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVLwE.png)

Again, when to_send is `to_send = {"field1": field1, "field2": field2};` it works, but I need to send the "something" key. Any idea on what might be wrong? Tyvm for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
var to_send = {};
to_send["something"] = {"field1": field1, "field2": field2};
to_send = JSON.stringify(to_send)
```